# Electric potential and Electronvolt

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, potential-energy, si-units

I am studying the electric potential energy and for the first time i red about the electric potential. The book Halliday et al. states that the electric potential can be defined as V = U/q where q is the test charge in the electric field, so the first question is: can the electric potential V be negative? In which cases this happens?

The second question is related to the electronvolt. The book states the electronvolt is the energy gained by an elementary charge, such as a proton or electron, to pass through a potential difference of 1 V. It says also that the eV can be obtained by the following formula: ΔV*q = -L where q is the test charge in the electric field and L is the work done on the test charge by the electric field. Now I tried to calculate the electronvolt for the electron and the proton but i am not sure if it is correct.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not post formulae as screenshots, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty Sorry buy I am new here and I don't know how to use it.

Comment: ... which is why I included a link to a tutorial where you can learn how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Take care not to confuse the *quantity* or *variable* $V$ (voltage) with the *unit* $\mathrm{V}$ (volt).

Voltage is measured in volts ($\mathrm{V}$). Energy is measured in joules ($\mathrm{J}$) or electronvolts ($\mathrm{eV}$). Charge is measured in coloumbs ($\mathrm{C}$). One volt is equal to one joule per coulomb.

Here's how you do it:
We know $q = -e = -1.6 \times 10^{-19} \mathrm{C}$. One electronvolt is defined as the energy gain of an electron that passes through a voltage of $V = 1\,\mathrm{V}$:
$$ 1\,\mathrm{eV} = -qV = eV = (1.6 \times 10^{-19} \mathrm{C}) \cdot (1\,\mathrm{V}) = 1.6 \times 10^{-19} \mathrm{J}. $$

Comment: So is it correct how I solved the exercises? What about the electric potential? Can it be negative according to the formula V = U/q (where U is the electric potential energy in a point of the space)?

Comment: What if you have to calculate the electron volt for a proton instead of an electron?

Comment: @AngeloGiannuzzi It would be the same process as for the electron since a proton and electron have the same charge but the electron is just negative.

Comment: @MrMineHeads So is it correct how I have done in the picture above? I set the voltage ΔV = -1 V because the proton starts from a point with a higher electric potential and ends to a point with a lower electric potential.

Comment: @AngeloGiannuzzi In this case, the proton would be losing energy since it starts at a higher potential and ends at a lower potential. So $\Delta V = -1 \text{ V}$ and $e = 1.602 \times 10^{-19} \text{ C}$ yields a negative answer (exactly $-1 \text{ eV}$ or $-1.602 \times 10^{-19} \text{ J}$).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, yes voltage is allowed to be negative. This happens when the reference voltage is at a higher potential than the measured voltage.

Voltage is just another name for electric potential difference, the important part being **difference**. This means voltage is calculated as a difference between two points meaning you need a reference, or a point where we define the potential to be $0$.

The definition of voltage actually is:

$$V_2 - V_1 = -\int_{P_1}^{P_2}{\mathbf{E}\,\cdot d\mathbf{l}}$$

where $\mathbf{E}$ is the electric field.

If we set the voltage at $P_1$ to be $0$, and it happens that the potential at $P_1$ is higher than $P_2$, $P_2$ will be negative.

Another way to find a voltage at a point it so set the voltage at $P_1 = \infty$ to $0$ and measure relatively that way. This has the consequence such that if you are in a negative electric field, any point $P_2$ will be at a lower voltage than at $P_1$, in other words, negative voltages.

Comment: My question was related to the electric potential V = U/q, not to the voltage. Here I use V to indicate the electric potential and ΔV to indicate the voltage.

Comment: They are the same.